# How to substitute the value of an atrribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I am stuck on this issue:

I have to output a input tag not as it is but modified. The tag name and the first attribute need to be rendered as they are. The second attribute's value need to be changed, and the third attribute (which don't even exists into the input tag) to be appended.

Here is example:

This is the input element:

```
<criterion class="equal" to="'text '"/>
```

This is the element I want to obtain on the output:

```
<criterion class="equal" to="text&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;" result="{$result}"/>
```

So part of the code is same in both xml files(input and output) therefore I am planing to use this pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But when the process encounters `to` attribute, then I need to explicitly define another pattern to handle the further part which differs. Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@to">
    <!--some staff here I don't know what-->
</xsl:template>
```

So ^^THESE^^ were just thoughts in my head. Please help me with this transformation.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Excuse me, I mistakenly hit the enter button, before completing my post. So it is complete now

Comment: You are on the right track here, but can you explain the actual logic for creating the output, as it is hard to tell from just one example. Are you removing apostrophes, and adding four non-breaking spaces at the end of the existing attribute value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you would do something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@to">
    <xsl:attribute name="to">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;')" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure whether to take your examples literally.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted!